# i cant set custom error message in buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate, spring boot

Tags: spring

// validator class

if(!user.getNewPassword().equals(user.getNewPasswordConfirmation())){
context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{error.user.passwordConfirmation}")
.addPropertyNode("newPassword")
.addConstraintViolation();

```
    return false;
}
return true;
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhrUI.png)
I have a message.properties file include it this key "error.user.passwordConfirmation"